# Automatically Build after save, for Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2015

When using Visual Studio, I'd like it to build my projects continuously. That is, after every save, kick off a build. I tend to work on large (35+ project) solutions, so having everything up-to-date saves me time when it comes to starting the app.

Roslyn gives you compiler errors as you type, but it doesn't actually run the full build process, which means you still need to tell VS to build and wait for it to complete before debugging or running tests.

Redgate's [.Net Demon](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/dotnet-demon/) used to do this kind of background compile, and it was really useful, but it's been discontinued because "Visual Studio 2015 will introduce Microsoft's new Roslyn compiler, with improvements which we believe make .NET Demon redundant."

Is there an option or extension to have Visual Studio 2015 automatically start a build after a file is saved or a project is modified in the IDE?

Comment: .NET Demon is also a lot faster because it only rebuilds the projects that changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a sample extension for Visual Commander that [runs Cppcheck on the saved file](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/extensions.html#OnDocumentSaved). You can replace Cppcheck with **DTE.ExecuteCommand("Build.BuildSolution");**

Comment: That looks like exactly what I need. Thanks! Also, Visual Commander looks really useful generally.

Answer (score 6):

I started developing a new open source extension that is called BuildOnSave and does exactly that: It builds the current solution or startup project when a file is saved.

It's available on the Visual Studio Extension Gallery: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2b31b977-ffc9-4066-83e8-c5596786acd0

May be you can give it a try. I would very much appreciate feedback.

Comment: looks nice, however on a solution with more than 1 projects I am getting this error:
"---------- BuildOnSave: Project: CTM-API, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ----------
C:\CyberGym\Projects\Dev\CTM\CTM.sln.metaproj : error MSB4057: The target "CTM-API" does not exist in the project.
Done building project "CTM.sln" -- FAILED.
========== BuildOnSave: 0 succeeded, 0 failed =========="
but On building the project manualy in VS everything works great.
Tnx anyway.

Comment: Hey Dudi, thanks for reporting the issue. I am currently testing a new version, which might have this problem fixed. Can you try the latest release from https://github.com/pragmatrix/BuildOnSave/releases and report further problems to the github issue tracker if possible. That would be great!

Comment: Hi, does this extension build only when the solution has no errors or will it try to build regardless of the state of solution/projects every time I save?

Comment: It builds every time a file is saved. Building only when Intellisense has not found any errors may be an interesting option to add.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Sergey Vlasov's answer, here's the modified version of the Visual Commander extension;

```
using EnvDTE;
using EnvDTE80;

public class E : VisualCommanderExt.IExtension
{
    private EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE;
    private EnvDTE.Events events;
    private EnvDTE.DocumentEvents documentEvents;
    private EnvDTE.BuildEvents buildEvents;

    public void SetSite(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE_, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package)
    {
        DTE = DTE_;
        events = DTE.Events;
        documentEvents = events.DocumentEvents;
        buildEvents = events.BuildEvents;

        buildEvents.OnBuildProjConfigDone += OnBuildProjectDone;
        documentEvents.DocumentSaved += OnDocumentSaved;
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        documentEvents.DocumentSaved -= OnDocumentSaved;
        buildEvents.OnBuildProjConfigDone -= OnBuildProjectDone;
    }

    private void OnDocumentSaved(EnvDTE.Document doc)
    {
        if(doc.Language == "CSharp")
        {
            var sb = DTE.Solution.SolutionBuild;
            sb.Build();
        }
    }

    private void OnBuildProjectDone(string project, string projectConfig, string platform, string solutionConfig, bool success)
    {
        //OutputString("Project " + project + " " + (success ? "build" : "failed to build"));   
    }

    private void OutputString(string line)
    {
        GetOutputPane().OutputString(line + System.Environment.NewLine);
    }

    private EnvDTE.OutputWindowPane GetOutputPane()
    {
        string cppcheckPaneName = "VCmd"; 
        foreach (EnvDTE.OutputWindowPane pane in 
            DTE.ToolWindows.OutputWindow.OutputWindowPanes)
        {
            if (pane.Name == cppcheckPaneName)
                return pane;
        }
        return DTE.ToolWindows.OutputWindow.OutputWindowPanes.Add(cppcheckPaneName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I created an extension last week that builds your solution with the method above, but I figured that building the solution with the DTE methods is causing cursor stalls and focus stealing issues when you type while the build is running, so I tried a different approach this weekend, and it worked quite well. It's now in the gallery, and I am looking for feedback: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2b31b977-ffc9-4066-83e8-c5596786acd0

Comment: @Armin I'll give it a go! If you add this as an answer you're more likely to drive traffic to your extension and u can give you an up vote :)