# Background compilation/On save compilation in Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, compilation, visual-studio-2015

I saw a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qsaEnSRzRpU) about Clang and plugin for Sublime Text allowing autocompilation on save. Can I do something like this in Visual Studio 2015? Maybe with an extension?

Thank you

Comment: Shift+Ctrl+B isn't that hard, really. Plus the old F7-based build shortcuts are there still. Ctrl+F7 to compile the active open source file.

Comment: Shift+Ctrl+B? My god, man, before long we'll have to dangle off the side of a mast of a sinking boat with a rifle in one hand and a laptop in the other and mutter, "Compile you son of a bitch!"

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33234498/automatically-build-after-save-for-visual-studio-2015

Comment: It **does** have a save before build option, so just use the right command.  :-)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf just give this a try https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2b31b977-ffc9-4066-83e8-c5596786acd0