# VS2017 with IIS Express not showing latest code changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017, iis-express

I've searched and come across similar topics, but they all relate to ASP.NET core projects.

I have a traditional ASP.NET MVC web app using the .NET 4.6.2 framework.

When I run this project without debugging (CTRL + F5) I am able to see all changes made to html, js, and css files by simply refreshing my browser.

However, if I make a code change to a .cs file and refresh the browser the change is not shown. It obviously needs to be recompiled - if I then manually build the project, and then refresh the browser the latest change made to the .cs file is then visible.

**Is there anyway I can make VS/IISExpress detect a code change, which then will automatically force the app to rebuild?**

Here is an example of what I would like:

https://youtu.be/yyBijyCI5Sk?t=880

^ He modifies code (c#), saves the file, jumps back to his browser, hits refresh which then forces a recompile for a few seconds and then reveals the changes.
The project in this video is using ASP.NET core, so I guess automatic compilation is a feature of it.

Any ideas how to achieve similar for non-core asp.net projects?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know of any way to let browser force VS to rebuild project, however based on video. You could use something like [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33234498/automatically-build-after-save-for-visual-studio-2015).

It is an extension which rebuilds your poject on save. So all .cs changes will be visible after save(build).

*I dont personaly use it, just know it exists*

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will take a look!

Answer (score 0):

Clear visual studio cache. step3 working fine for me.
Step 1: clear the Component Cache

1. Close Visual Studio (ensure devenv.exe is not present in the Task Manager)
2. Delete the %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache directory
3. Restart Visual Studio.

Step 2: cleanup your user’s temp folder

Delete the %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp directory.

If all the above fails. you can try the hard route.

Step 3: delete the contents from the following folders

%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon